# Is there a way to insert non-breaking space between words automatically?

Tags: spacing

Is there a way to convince LaTeX to automatically add tildes in front of one- and two-letter words, numbers and such simple things (in normal mode, not in math mode)?

I know there are preprocessors for that, but manually launching them is tedious.

What's the best way to achieve it automatically?

Comment: ,@peci1 Does [Automatic non-breaking spaces in proper name initials](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166536/automatic-non-breaking-spaces-in-proper-name-initials) help?

Comment: this question deals with one-letter words in czech: [Is there way to put hard space after defined words?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46955/579).  the recommendation is to just get used to typing `~` when needed.

Comment: Thanks @AboAmmar and barbara beeton. It seems like all the proposed solutions use lualatex, which I don't have any experience with. But I'll give it a chance. It's a pity that luavlna has not been in CTAN yet. However, I still wonder TeX doesn't do such a basic typographic stuff on its own.

Comment: @peci1 it isn't on CTAN because it needs some cleanup, but this reminds me that I should take a look at it :)

Comment: My general idea was to have an automated tool to insert the tildes to many places where it could be good, and to have a new command that would prevent a tilde to appear. But I'm not sure luavlna can do that...