# Avoid Single Letters at the End of Lines [Polish Language Rule]

Tags: typography

I'm writing the thesis in Polish language and one of our typography rule is that there can't be single letter at the and of line, like (*w* and *i*):

```
Tomek poszedl do sklepu w % <-- not allowed
mieście, żeby kupić jabłka i % <-- not allowed
bułki
```

I'm using LaTeX and the solution proposed by @topskip in this post:

[one-letter word at the end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line)

produce multiple errors during compliation. Additionaly, this content was posted few yeras ago. So I'm wondering is there any new tip that can solve my problem?

Comment: Lua(La)TeX changed 'recently'. Most likely you need `\usepackage{luatex85}` (and other remedies ;-))

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46955/is-there-way-to-put-hard-space-after-defined-words/98826#98826. In my answer you must disable macros before new section. But you will not problems in reading comments, because they are in Polish.

Comment: I updated the title of the question. I hope that's ok for you. I think the new title is more accurate and Google-friendlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `LaTeX` (i guess `pdflatex`) and not `LuaTeX` which was used in the referred solution. Am I right?

---

### Before You Start Your Thesis / Document

Following the LaTeX wikibook ([link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Polish)) about the internationalization in the case of Polish:

> Polish has many single letter connectives [...] To ensure that LaTeX won't set them as last letter in
>   the line, you have to use **non breakable space** [...]

```
i~słodka
a~także
i~ciała
i~Basi
```

> So the solution is to simply connect the following word with a ~ (tilde, also
>   known as a *non breakable space*).

The *non breakable space* feature of the tilde character is a core LaTeX feature (thanks at [@DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)).

---

By the way, I googled for *polish single letter latex* and the solution was the third entry in my hit list.

---

### When You Have Already Finished Your Document

Maybe you can use a **text editor** like **Notepad++** (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and **search and replace** `_z_`, and `_w_` and so on with `_z~`, and `_w~` and so on (with `_` I want to indicate a space).

**Notepad++** also can search and replace in multiple files at once. Be sure that you try it on a **backup copy** of your actual document!

[image]

With **regular expressions** you may be able to have even more sophisticated ways. But I do not know much about that.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am using LaTeX, precisely pdflatex. I know this solution, but when the thesis has more than 50 pages it becomes quite exhausting to straighten up all the single letters at the end of line.

Comment: @barnaba At least the solution will help others which are about to start writing. Maybe you can use an **text editor** like **notepad++** (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and **search and replace** **"space"z"space"**, and **"space"w"space"** and so on with **"space"z~**, and **"space"w~** and so on.

Comment: `~` is core latex (and plain tex) not babel

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the clarification. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @Dr. Manuel Kuehner, for me that's the easiest and the quickest solution, and what is the most important it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

here's a command I used for this (I had several .tex files to modify):

```
find -name "*.tex" -exec sed -i 's/\( [^0-9\| ]\) \([^\|]\)/\1~\2/g' {} \;
```

It adds non-breakable space after a single character in between spaces that is not a number, a pipe or a space itself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably should add an OS-remark.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of `babel` (3.58) with `luatex` there is predefined ‘transform’ for this purpose (also available in Czech and Slovak):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\babelprovide[transforms = oneletter.nobreak]{polish}

\begin{document}

\hsize=1pt

Tomek poszedl do sklepu w % <-- not allowed
mieście, żeby kupić jabłka i % <-- not allowed
bułki

\end{document}
```

[image: Polish one letter no break]